# Handling method when OncePerRequestFilter is not needed

Tags: spring, kotlin

We used a filter to check if the JWT is valid, but the filter also works for URLs that don't use a JWT.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    val securityProperties: SecurityProperties
) {
    @Bean
    protected fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()

            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .and()

            .addFilterBefore(JwtFilter(securityProperties), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

        return http.build()
    }


    @Bean
    protected fun passwordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()
}
```

/api/auth/** does not require a jwt token, so the filter works even if it is omitted as in the code above.

```
class JwtFilter(
    private val securityProperties: SecurityProperties
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    companion object {
        const val PREFIX = "Bearer "
    }

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val token = resolvedToken(request)
        if (token.isEmpty())
            throw InvalidTokenException
        try {
            val claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(securityProperties.key)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)

            val jwtHeader = claims.header
            val jwtDody = claims.body

            val expiration = jwtDody.expiration

            if (expiration.before(Date())) {
                throw ExpiredTokenException
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw InvalidTokenException
        }
    }


    private fun resolvedToken(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
        val bearerToken: String? = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
        bearerToken?.let {
            if (bearerToken.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
                return bearerToken.substring(PREFIX.length)
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

The filter works even in places where jwt is not needed in the JWT filter code. Please tell me the code to exclude the filter

Comment: Fix your filter. If there is no JWT added just continue don't throw an exception.

Comment: I don't know how to edit the filter

Comment: I explicitly told you (well almost) what to do. Don't throw an exception. Only parse and validate the token if it is there, if not, just continue the chain.